# Multi Select Drop Down validation in Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm trying to validate multi-select dropdown form validation in Codeigniter and I'm using custom validate callback method for the validation.  I tried several StackOverflow answers, but none of them worked for me. Am I missing something?

This is my view code.

```html
<?php echo form_open_multipart('Register/user_register') ?>
     <div class="form-group">
    <label for="musicGen">Select Your Music Genre</label>
    <?php echo form_error('musicGen'); ?>
    <select class="form-control" name="musicGen[]" multiple="multiple" id="musicGen">
     <?php
     foreach ($genre as $row) {
      echo '<option class="form-control" value="' . $row->genreId . '">' . $row->genreName . '</option>';
     }
     ?>
    </select>
   </div>
<?php echo form_close() ?>
```

This is my controller.

```html
$this->form_validation->set_rules('musicGen', 'Music Genre', 'required|callback_multiple_select');

public function multiple_select()
 {
  $music_genre = $this->input->post('musicGen');

  if (is_null($music_genre)) {
   $this->form_validation->set_message('multiple_select', 'Select at least one Music Genre');
   return false;
  } else {
   return true;
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use a callback function, unless you want a user to select more than one option.
You can use the below code in your code

```
if (empty($_POST['musicGen'])) {
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('musicGen', 'Music Genre', 'required',array('required' =>'Select at least one Music Genre'));
   }
```

Comment: Yes. I just wanted to make sure that the user to selected at least one option and your answer worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 possibilities to approach this:

use just validation rule "**required**", for that you may not index the name of the input field, change it to name="musicGen"`:

```
<select class="form-control" name="musicGen" multiple="multiple" id="musicGen">
```

and

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('musicGen', 'Music Genre', 'required');
```

or you use the callback function "**multiple_select**" with the indexed name field. This makes more sense, as your callback requires to have at least one option selected (checking with is_null)
You could also want to check for more than one option selected, do this with count

```
<select class="form-control" name="musicGen[]" multiple="multiple" id="musicGen">
```

and simple change you validation rule to:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('musicGen', 'Music Genre', 'callback_multiple_select');

public function multiple_select()
{
    $music_genre = $this->input->post('musicGen');
    if (count($music_genre)<2) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('multiple_select', 'Select at least two Music Genre');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I do this in Codeigniter 4